# Can we set minimum value for FrameworkPropertyMetadata default value

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Here is the code:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( (uint) 100,...
```

We can set in max value here as 100, is there a way to set minimum value too? Let's say I want this default value to be between 5 and 100? I looked all over Google did not find any answers. Can anybody please suggest a solution. Thanks!

Code tried according to Reed Copsey

```
public static bool IsValidReading(object value)
{
    uint v = (uint)value;
    return (!v.Equals(0));
}
```

Full code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Result =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ResultLimit", typeof( uint ), typeof( UI ),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( ( uint )10, new PropertyChangedCallback( ResultChanged ) ), IsValidReading );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not the max value - it's the *default* value.

There is no way to specify the min or max in the metadata directly.  This should be handled via a [Callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) registered with the Dependency Property.

Comment: More specifically, a `CoerceValueCallback` would probably be the best choice since it gives access to the dependency object allowing the range of values to be configurable.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - Is it possible for you to show some code? I tried adding (IsValidReading) method and had code in it to return (!v.equals(0)). But this is not working the way i was thinking as it is still allowing user to enter 0.

Comment: @NoviceMe: Did you unbox the value in the callback?  A boxed unsigned integer 0 is not considered equal to a literal integer 0.  You would have to unbox it first or compare it like this: `!v.Equals(0U)`.

Comment: @Reed Copsey- I added the code i used above in the question. It does hit that code and checks if value is not 0.

Comment: @NoviceMe Can you update to show the call to Register?  (So you show the full set of code)

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Added the call please take a look.

Comment: @NoviceMe As Jeff mentioned, you should probably do this in a CoerceValueCallback.  See the link I posted for an example.  The validation will return false - which you can use to *show* that the value isn't valid, but it won't prevent it from being set.  CoerceValueCallback can be used to prevent a bad value from being set in the first place, which is what I think you want.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - I tried CoerceValueCallback, but still if i enter 0 in the box it still keeps it as 0 even thoug in CoerceValueCallback i am changing 0 to 1? Is there any way to change value of 0 to 1 in the textbox as soon as it is entered?